# Is there a way to use a file's location from a string stored in a cell in Index/Match?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a bunch of Excel files which are synced across several computers through Google Drive's desktop syncing software. The file structure is this:

MainFolder\Workers\FoldersWithWorkerNamesasNames
MainFolder\Supervisors\ReportsGoHere

Now, I want to look through the Workers' files through Index/Match, but since different Supervisors are going to use their Google Drive accounts, the file structure is bound to change. I can store the exact file location as a string in a cell through VBA, but is there a way I can call the data in that file through Index/Match?

=Index('FileCustomPathandName.xlsb'Sheet1!A:A, Match(A1,'FileCustomPathandName.xlsb'Sheet1!B:B,0))

Where FileCustomPathandName.xlsb changes?

This is basically me wondering if there's a way to force Excel to use relative file references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel tries to restrict you to relative file paths. This is good, because what you are describing could have all kinds of side effects. Tying many Excel sheets together is almost never a good solution, even as a temporary fix. I would rethink this approach.

Regardless, if you open both Excel sheets programmatically (ie. through VBA), you should be able to use Excel's built-in `INDIRECT` to point to workbooks by name dynamically (enabling you to populate `INDEX` and `MATCH` with the correct references):

[image: Indirect Example]

In this example, `Book1.xlsx` on the left references `Book2.xlsx` on the right. It does this by passing the filename into `INDIRECT`. Note that I split up the formula so you can easily see how to build the correct input string for both `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

While this works, it's not the ideal way to link Excel sheets. If you truly need to dynamically link Excel workbooks, you can write a more advanced method with VBA and use the `INDEX`/`MATCH` functionality in a module instead.

Comment: I'm still new to VBA, which is why I'm using an amateur subroutine to do what I need. Thanks for the idea about using INDIRECT.